# How to change the timestamp security header in a wcf client?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, timestamp, soap-client

I am trying to modify the default expiration time of the security header which is 5 min to 1 min.
One of the security policies of the server is a timestamp (the date of the request), with a Time to live of one minute.

Any idea?

I tried it creating a custom binding with no success.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:u=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns:o=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id=\"uuid-6f772493-4b86-4695-b415-316a916119ec-2\">
                <u:Created>2019-05-23T12:14:26.920Z</u:Created>
                **<u:Expires>2019-05-23T12:19:26.920Z</u:Expires>**
            </u:Timestamp>
```

An this is what we need:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:u=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns:o=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id=\"uuid-6f772493-4b86-4695-b415-316a916119ec-2\">
                <u:Created>2019-05-23T12:14:26.920Z</u:Created>
                **<u:Expires>2019-05-23T12:15:26.920Z</u:Expires>**
            </u:Timestamp>
```

Comment: TTL : Time To Live actually means the number of hops an IP takes before it is not forwarded to prevent routing loops.  You may be trying to change the wrong property.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.localclientsecuritysettings.timestampvalidityduration?view=netframework-4.8 but you need to create a custombinding to set it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was creating a custom binding:

```
protected override SecurityBindingElement CreateMessageSecurity()
{
     SecurityBindingElement security;
     security.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
     security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
     security.LocalClientSettings.TimestampValidityDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
     security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
     security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
     return security;          
}
```